# Images loosing their aspect ratio when they are displayed as flex-items in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

I've just come along a strange bug in Firefox. I have an image displayed as a flex-item and want it to shrink down to a maximum size using max-width and height: auto. It works perfectly in all browsers I tested, except Firefox. I guess it has something to do with the default alignment of flex-items which is stretch. I overwrote it to flex-start, which worked fine, but not in Firefox.

Has anybody else experienced this?

```
img {
    max-width: 50px;
    height: auto;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

See this Codepen for an example: http://codepen.io/kaesetoast/pen/PPevbv

Answer (score 2):

Use `flex-basis` insread of `max-width`

```
img {
    flex-basis: 50px;
    height: auto;
    }
```

```css
img {
  flex-basis: 50px;
  height: auto;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1440/1500/" width="1440" height="1500" alt="">
</div>
```

**Tested in FF 41.0.2**

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm. Didn't think about flex-basis :-)